# Tableau: Create a newline between text using a calculated field

Tags: excel, formatting, tableau-api

I have a dimension pill on the text mark in Tableau. Currently different events appear side by side.

**e.g.**  `[Event1] [Event2] [Event3]`

I want them to be stacked, cant seem to do this with alignment tools. What is the correct syntax to create a new line using a calculated field?

I have tried :

`[Event] + "       "`(increased the white space) with no results.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply enter in a newline like so:

```
[Event 1] + "
" + [Event 2] + "
" + [Event 3]
```

Or use `CHAR(10)`:

```
[Event 1] + CHAR(10) + [Event 2] + CHAR(10) + [Event 3]
```